# How to edit magento topmenu

Tags: php, xml, magento

i was to the topmenu.phtml to edit the topmenu magento, but the code found:

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

I need the file that mounts the menu, which contains  `<ul>`,  `<li>`, `class="submenu"` where is this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html is built in `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu::_getHtml` if you are using Magento 1.7.x.x or in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::renderCategoriesMenuHtml` for lower versions.

There is a chance that the second option is used for 1.7.x.x also if your theme is built that way.

Take a look [at this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/7329/146) if you want to add items to the menu.

Comment: thank u, i need do add items, but in other times i edit other things

Answer (score 0):

You could try this extension: http://www.reddotdevelopment.com/store/extensions/magento-custom-navigation-bar-with-direct-links-cms-pages-and-categories-extension